# webgrid sort not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I'm using webgrid to show data from my data base. The problem is that sort option is not working
Here is my webgrid code

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage:true ,canSort:true, rowsPerPage :4);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", htmlAttributes: new { id = "datatable" },
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",

        selectedRowStyle : "webgrid-selected-row",
        footerStyle : "webgrid-footer",
                 rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                 alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
        columns: grid.Columns(
     grid.Column(header: "", format:  (item) =>

                    Html.ActionLink("Détails", "Details", new { id = item.id_client }, new { @class = "details" }), style: "actions"),

           grid.Column(header: "", format:  (item) => Html.ActionLink("Modifier", "Edit", new { id = item.id_client }, new { @class = "modifier" }),style : "actions"),

                    grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Supprimer", "Delete", new { id = item.id_client }, new { @class = "supprimer" }), style: "actions"),

                    grid.Column("Nom",canSort: true),
                    grid.Column("Prenom", "Prénom",canSort:true),
        grid.Column("Email")));


                        }
```

Comment: ok, is the sort not working for a particular column or for all columns ? also see [this link](http://yassershaikh.com/mvc-3-web-grid-sorting-not-working/) may help you

Comment: yes it works with only some columns (it works with both int columns and string columns but not all of them)

Comment: I think that the problem is when the grid contains more than one page

Comment: Thank you yasser it was exactly what i want :)

Comment: great ! post an answer to your question, for other's future references. Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add the list of  name columns for your webgrid, for example:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(canPage:true ,canSort:true, rowsPerPage :4);

grid.Bind(Model,columnNames: new[] { "Nom", "Prenom"}); //adding names of columns

grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
@grid.GetHtml(...
```

Sometimes web grid can't understand how bind your model with columns.

Comment: Hi James, in my webgrid 7000 records are there.i used webgrid.in this actionlink column sorting not working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, James's answer worked for me. The sort links were working for some of the columns and not others, adding the columnNames: made it work properly.
Steve

Comment: hi.i used webgrid in my application.in this action link column sort functionality not working. can any one help me.